# How to assign value to a apex variable in visualforce page ,using javascript/jQuery?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery

```
<apex:page controller="CurrencyCon" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert();
        var x=1111111111111;
        $('[id$=abc]').val(x);
        var y='{!a}';
        alert(y);
    });
</script>
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:form > 
    <apex:inputHidden value="{!a}" id="abc"/>
</apex:form>
     <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
        <apex:outputText value="$ {0, number, ########,##,#0.00}">
            <apex:param value="{!a}" />
        </apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText value="$ {0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}" >
            <apex:param value="{!b}" />
        </apex:outputText>
        <apex:outputText value="${0, number, ###,###,###,##0.00}">
            <apex:param value="{!c}" />
        </apex:outputText>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

a,b,c are declared in currencycon (controller).
I want to change "a" value using jquery.

Comment: is there some reason you are not using the `j$ = jQuery.noConflict();`  ?https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Apps_with_jQuery

Answer (score 5):

You can define actionFunction, it will invoke controller method, and pass parameter from javascript

```
    <apex:actionFunction name="jsFunction" action="{!apexMethod}" >
        <apex:param value="" name="paramName"/>
    </apex:actionFunction>


    public void apexMethod() {
        String yourValue = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('paramName');
    }
```

use this in javascript like this:

```
...
jsFunction('yourValue');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            alert();
            var x=1111111111111;
            $('[id$=abc]').val(x);
            var y='{!a}';
            alert(y);
           document.getElementById('{!$Component.aId}').value='your value';
        });
    </script>

    <apex:outputText id="aId" value="$ {0, number, ########,##,#0.00}">
          <apex:param value="{!a}" />
    </apex:outputText>
```

---

Using Jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert();
        var x=1111111111111;
        $('[id$=abc]').val(x);
        var y='{!a}';
        alert(y);
        $( 'span[id$=aId]' ).val('your value');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,my requirement is before it is printing into outputText I need to change that , I have to print that into outputText.

Comment: so make that that outputtext `display:none` then `document.getElementById('{!$Component.aId}').value='your value';` after this link just make your outputtext `display:block`

Comment: @manoj Can you add more info in your question?

Comment: Thanks Rathan for your response.I got the reason why new value is not saving in "a".The reason is we are trying to assign the value using jQuery/js .But that value is in input hidden tag.It is not reaching the back-end.In output text we tried to print the value .Here that value is coming from back-end. Until we reload the page the new value won't be effect on  "a".for that we need to write an action function and rerender that outputText portion.